# Makefile: ifeq fails with findstring

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to test if a file exist based on makefile input. The makefile is the following

```
AAA = $(wildcard *.aaa)

%:
    @echo $(AAA);
    @echo "$*.aaa";
    @echo "$(findstring $*.aaa, $(AAA))";
ifeq "$(findstring $*.aaa, $(AAA))" "" 
    @echo "No file named $*.aaa";
else
    @echo "File named $*.aaa found";
endif
```

Suppose you have in the dir a file `temp.aaa`, then clearly the output of `make temp` is:

```
temp.aaa
temp.aaa
temp.aaa
File named temp.aaa found
```

But the last line of the output of `make abcd` is wrong:

```
temp.aaa
abcd.aaa

File named abcd.aaa found
```

it fails testing condition of `ifeq` that returns false when it is clearly true. I've tryed all possible variations in syntax but now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `$*` and other automatic variables outside of a recipe line.  Recipe lines are ONLY those lines which start with a TAB character and are passed to the shell.  The make statements like `ifeq`, etc. are preprocessor directives, and are parsed when make reads in the makefile, long before make starts to run the recipe (and long before make knows what the value of `$*` will be).

You have to rewrite your conditional using shell syntax, so it's part of the recipe:

```
%:
        @echo $(AAA);
        @echo "$*.aaa";
        @echo "$(findstring $*.aaa, $(AAA))";
        @if [ "$(findstring $*.aaa, $(AAA))" = "" ]; then \
            echo "No file named $*.aaa"; \
        else \
            echo "File named $*.aaa found"; \
        fi
```

You can also use make's `$(if ...)` function, if you want, and if your version of GNU make is new enough to support it.